# JS on SVG--getting innerHTML of an element

Tags: javascript, xml, svg

I wanted to extract some data from an SVG file. I know that SVG is XML, so I thought that it would be pretty easy to coax the data out with JS.

So, I wanted to get a bunch of text extracted from an SVG. So, I fired up chrome's JS console, and tried doing some stuff. I needed to get all the `tspan` elements in an array, extract their text, and categorize it.

I'm referring to http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/Light_spectrum.svg at the moment.

So, I use `a = document.getElementsByTagName('tspan')`. Now, I try `a[20].innerHTML`, and get `undefined`. Reasonable; it's not HTML and iirc innerHTML is nonstandard anyways.

Then I try `a[20].childNodes[0]` and get `"ELF"`. OK, that's what I wanted. But, for some reason, this object is treated like a string, but can't be converted to one. If I try to convert it (so that I can use stuff like `matches()` and `indexOf()`), I get `"[object Text]"`. Delving into `Text.prototype` doesn't help--I can't find any function that converts it to a string.

So how can one get the innerHTML of an SVG object through JS?

Comment: Also, for some reason, the prototype shows that certain other built in functions that one normally sees in HTML (in fact, exactly the ones which I need) are all missing. Great--now the W3C is conspiring against me...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Select the element like you have, but use the following to access its text:

```
var content = a[20].textContent;
```

This is no replacement for `innerHTML` inside SVG, but will work as long as you only want to extract text and no markup.

Comment: what significance is index 20, by the way? This index value would never hypothetically be any other number I assume?

Comment: @NateNeuhaus The 20 is just referring to OPs code given. Here the 20th `<tspan>` element should be selected. Can be any other. Main aspect is the property (`textContent`) to use afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

A [`Text` node](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1312295772) looks like a string when you inspect it in the console, but it is not a string. For a string, you want the [`nodeValue`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-F68D080). Try:

```
document.querySelectorAll('tspan')[20].childNodes[0].nodeValue
```